# don't know how to solve this exercice

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I must calculate the exchange rate, in legal tender, for an exact amount. The exact paper money and coins must be inserted into an array. I am stuck in this step and do not know how to solve it.

```
function countChange(amount) {
    const currency = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01];
    const change = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) {
        const value = currency[i];
        if (value <= amount) {
            change.push(value)
        }

    }
    return change;

};


console.log(countChange(500.26));
```

Comment: What is expected output for `500.26`

Comment: `exchange rate`  your question seems a bit confusing, what has calculating change got to do with exchange rates?.  To calculate coinage just keep dividing by the biggest number, and then from the whole number is your coinage, the remainder is for the next lowest coinage..

Comment: This is the kind of exercise that nearly everyone here has to solve at least once during the learning process. How would **you** (AKA **Not your program**) proceed to count the currency to give ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is simple example.

Just simply iterate for each coinage size, just divide the current total amount by each coinage size, if there is any coinage then push this into an array.

```js
function countChange(amount) {
    const currency = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01];
    const change = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) {
        const coinsize = currency[i];
        //how many coins?
        const coins = Math.trunc(amount / coinsize);
        //remove these from total
        amount -= coinsize * coins;
        //fix rounding problems.
        amount = Math.round(amount * 100) / 100;
        //add to our result
        if (coins > 0)
        {
            change.push({
                coinsize,
                coins
            });
        }
    }
    return change;
};


console.log(countChange(500.26));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're expecting :

```js
function countChange(amount) {
    const currency = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01];
    const change = [];
    var changed = 0;
    while(changed < amount){
        for(var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++){
            if(amount-currency[i] >= 0){
                change.push(currency[i]);
                changed+=currency[i];
                amount-=currency[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return change;

}

console.log(countChange(500.26))
```

Comment: But that's the wrong result... that adds up to 500.25, not 500.26

Comment: No probs, the other answer is better tho